# Thread Pool join hangs when oversubscribing threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm having an issue with a thread hanging when joining my threads in a thread pool I have created. The issue only occurs if I loop over the thread pool execution a large number of times.

I have a thread pool class like the following;

```
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

class ThreadPool
{
    public:

        ThreadPool()
        {
            m_shutdown.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            createThreads(1);
        }

        ThreadPool(std::size_t numThreads)
        {
            m_shutdown.store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            createThreads(numThreads);
        }

        void add_job(std::function<void()> new_job)
        {
            {
                std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_jobMutex);
                m_jobQueue.push(new_job);

            }

            m_notifier.notify_one();

        }

        void waitFinished()
        {
            {
              std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_jobMutex);
              m_finished.wait(lock, [this] {return m_jobQueue.empty(); }); //&& busy == 0
            }

            m_shutdown.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
            m_notifier.notify_all();

            for (std::thread& th : m_threads)
            {
                th.join();
            }
            m_threads.clear();

        }

    private:

        using Job = std::function<void()>;
        std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
        std::queue<Job> m_jobQueue;
        std::condition_variable m_notifier;
        std::condition_variable m_finished;
        std::mutex m_jobMutex;
        std::atomic<bool> m_shutdown;

        void createThreads(std::size_t numThreads)
        {
            // Settup threads
            m_threads.reserve(numThreads);
            for (int i = 0; i != numThreads; ++i)
            {
                m_threads.emplace_back(std::thread([this]()
                {
                    // Infinite loop to consume tasks from queue and execute
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Job job;

                        {
                            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_jobMutex);
                            m_notifier.wait(lock, [this] {return !m_jobQueue.empty() || m_shutdown.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); });

                            if (m_shutdown.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) || m_jobQueue.empty())
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                            job = std::move(m_jobQueue.front());

                            m_jobQueue.pop();

                        }

                        job();
                        m_finished.notify_one();

                    }
                }));
            }
        }
};
```

I run this in a simple manner, like the following;

```
void threader (int x) {

  std::cout<<"In threaded function: "<<x<<std::endl;

}

int main()
{

  //outer loop
  for (auto i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    //Thread pool
    int num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    ThreadPool test_pool(num_threads);

    // Assign work
    for (int j = 0; j < 48; j++) {
      test_pool.add_job(std::bind(threader, j));
    }

    test_pool.waitFinished();
    std::cout<<"Thread Pool Done"<<std::endl;

  }
  
}
```

After a number of outer loop iterations the `join` in the `waitFinished` hangs for a thread. The error only seems to occur after a number of iterations of the outer loop large enough. I have investigated this and can see that the `threader` function get's called 48 times, so looks like all threads complete. It seems to be the joining of threads in the `waitFinished` function of the `ThreadPool` that is causing the hang.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong ?

Many thanks!

Comment: If the code hangs, what does the debugger show? Are there any threads running besides main? If so, why and what are they doing? Where is main stuck exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, apologies, I'm not so familiar with the debugger for multithreading, this is what info threads tells me;

Comment: * 1    Thread 0x7fe6e6dff740 (LWP 3092588) "test" __pthread_clockjoin_ex (threadid=140629675853568, thread_return=0x0, clockid=<optimized out>, abstime=<optimized out>, 
    block=<optimized out>) at pthread_join_common.c:145

Comment: 835  Thread 0x7fe6e5dfc700 (LWP 3093425) "test" futex_wait_cancelable (private=<optimized out>, expected=0, futex_word=0x7ffe0ebcef94)
    at ../sysdeps/nptl/futex-internal.h:183

Comment: It looks like one thread has not finished for some reason. There might a be a race condition between you notifying the thread for the last time and it actually starting to `wait`. Notification only wakes up currently waiting threads. I guess you could change it to `wait_for` and just rely on that `while(true)` to retry. In general, your issue is using a condition in the condition variable which is not protected by the mutex used by the condition - `m_shutdown`.